# Why do I get this typeError?: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

Hey i'm currently trying to use tkinter to make a calculator without buttons, basically just a regular old input using the Text function but i'm having quite some trouble and can't figure out why.

Here's how my code looks (at least the important part):

```
def calculator():
    global inputWindow, outputWindow
    displayCalculator = Canvas(mainWindow, width=796, height=796, bg=clrMain)
    displayCalculator.grid(column=2, row=1)

    #inputbaren för kalkulatorn
    inputWindow = Text(displayCalculator, width=70, height=1, bg=clrMain, font=("Times", 15))
    displayCalculator.create_window(4,15, anchor=NW, window=inputWindow) #Skapar objektet

    #knapp för inputbaren
    bEnter = Button(displayCalculator, text="=", command=output, bg=clrButton, width=7, height=1)
    displayCalculator.create_window(710,15, anchor=NW, window=bEnter) #Skapar objektet

    #information
    lblCommands = Label(displayCalculator, text="Addition: + | Subtraktion: - | Multiplikation: * | Divition: / ", bg=clrMain, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
    displayCalculator.create_window(4,52, anchor=NW, window=lblCommands)
    lblExample = Label(displayCalculator, text="100+100 | Ingen mellanrum mellan talen.", bg=clrMain, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
    displayCalculator.create_window(4,84, anchor=NW, window=lblExample)
    #canvasDivider = Canvas(displayCalculator, width=780, height=1, bg=clrMenu)
    #displayCalculator.create_window(4,130, anchor=NW, window=canvasDivider)

    #output window
    outputWindow = Text(displayCalculator, width=70, height=10, bg=clrMain, font=("Times", 15))
    displayCalculator.create_window(4,120, anchor=NW, window=outputWindow) #Skapar objektet7

#outputwindown för kalkylatorn

def calculation(usrInput):
    calculation 
    usrInput = str(usrInput)

    if usrInput.isdigit():
        return float(usrInput)

    for c in ('-','+','*','/'):
        left, op, right = usrInput.partition(c)
        if op == '*':
            return calculation(left) * calculation(right)
        elif op == '/':
            return calculation(left) / calculation(right)
        elif op == '+':
            return calculation(left) + calculation(right)
        elif op == '-':
            return calculation(left) - calculation(right)

def output():
    global inputWindow, outputWindow 
    outputWindow.configure(state=NORMAL)
    usrInput = inputWindow.get("1.0",END)

    print(calculation(usrInput))

    inputWindow.delete('1.0', 'end-1c')
    outputWindow.insert(END, usrInput)
    outputWindow.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

btw im just trying to print out the written message in the inputwindow "outputWindow.insert(END, usrInput)" i'm just trying to get the "print(calculation(usrInput))" to work.

Thanks for the help! (:

Comment: By the way, instead of four if-elif-elif-elif you can just use `eval(str(calculation(left)) + op + str(calculation(right)))`

Comment: You need to give a [*minimal reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the **whole** code.

Comment: You're calling the `calculation` function from itself (recursion). What are you doing it for?

Comment: ***Why do I get this typeError?: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'***: May I see the output of `print(left, op, right)` just before the Traceback

Comment: Hey everyone! Thanks for the help but i managed to find the problem. Was trying to use Text instead of Entry